# ethernet usb ports are dead

Tags: raspbian

All ports were functioning properly yesterday until "rpi-update". Then after reboot, they stopped functioning and red light started blinking. I changed power supply. Red light is stable now but ports are not functioning.What should i do?

Comment: What about the Green LED? What is that doing?

Comment: It flashes when rpi is booting. On boot, i cant see my ip that i assigned earlier..

Answer (score 1):

I've read something before that newer kernels cause this exact issue. Try **reverting back to an old kernel** or wiping your card and downloading a fresh, new image. If a new image doesn't work (It should), go for an old one.

Also, something might have messed up the update. Do whatever you can to reconnect the pi to the internet, and run the update again. Wifi should work on one of the ports.